# Ecplise CDT .settings folder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

How can I make Eclipse CDT store its .settings folder in the project folder instead of .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings ?

More general, can Eclipse put all the settings there?

Background for the question is: I think there are many settings that I wand to put into SVN to archive and share in the project, but putting the .metedata branch into revision control seems to be the wrong way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

These settings are for the plugin so will be stored in the plugin's metadata area. I don't think there is a way to change this short of hacking on the plugin yourself.

I'm not familiar with the CDT plugin, but for many other plugins you can override the platform preferences with project-specific settings. These should be stored under the project and you could then commit them to SVN.